# string variable not working with

Tags: python, tkinter

I have my main window, which i refer to as `mainroot`, and when i press a button the secondary window `root` should appear 
in `root` there is an entry and i want it to be assigned to "hohoho" whenever i press anykey, so i tied it to KeyRelease event.
All i mentioned above is working when there is no `mainroot`, As in this code:

```
import tkinter as Tk
# mainroot=Tk.Tk()
root=Tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")

myvar=Tk.StringVar()
entry=Tk.Entry(root,)
entry.pack()
entry.configure(textvariable=myvar)

entry.bind('<KeyRelease>',lambda event:printing())

def printing():
    myvar.set("hohohohohohoho")
    print('myvar is',myvar.get())
    print('value is',entry.get())
root.mainloop()
# mainroot.mainloop()
```

but if you commented the `root.mainloop()` and uncommented `root.mainloop()` and `# mainroot.mainloop()` the text shown in `entry`stops following `myvar`.

what i found is that `myvar` is not working properly as it should.
anyone have any idea what am doing wrong or is this bug in tkinter or what?????

I know that `entry.trace()` is more elegant but i didn't use it because i am not very familiar with it.

thank you

any hint will be appreciated

Comment: You can't have two root windows. If you need a second window, create an instance of `Toplevel`. Widgets are in a hierarchy, and that hierarchy can only have one root.

Comment: can you explain in details or direct me to topic??

Comment: thank you very much, i handled it.
thank you again.
how can i mark your comment as Solution

Comment: A point, don't use `.set` function if variable linked to entry !

Comment: sorry, but why? 
I am fairly new to python and tkinter altogether, can you explain??